# How can I integrate CA in WebSphere Portal

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, ca

Now I have a problem like this:We were using the WebSphere Portal Portal for users,The user has a CA system.Users use keys to open the computer, the CA to authenticate keys,Now users want WebSphere Portal login also use CA authentication keys.Now I can check the information shows it is a process of configure WebSphere console,Maybe this is a root certificate and the certificate server configuration,May I study in the right direction.So I don't know what to do now.

Oh, almost forget an important instructions, my WebSphere Portal version is IBM® WebSphere® Portal Express V8.5.

I am a Chinese, English is very poor, all is the translation software translation, pray you can understand, if you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Portal documents client-certificate based authentication specifically, see

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/security/certauth.html

Note, they do not recommend any kind of fallback for users without a certificate -- it's all or nothing.